# What if I have a list of questions?

Tags: discussion

What if I have more than a few questions about a chapter in a book?
I don't think it's a good idea to make many threads about the same chapter.

Comment: You wouldn't be the first to ask a long string of questions; there is [precedent](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a504%20%22Harry%20Potter%22) for this. I would try to limit the number of questions to a reasonable rate, though (say, three or maybe four a day) so that the board doesn't get saturated with too many questions from the same book all at once.

Answer (score 5):

[The policy for ELL is clear](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/767/should-we-mark-questions-containing-multiple-sub-questions-as-too-broad-until): do not ask multiple queries in a single question on ELL. It doesn't fit the StackExchange model where questions can be left as a future reference (making it easier to merge duplicate questions), given multiple individualized answers, and can be voted on independently by users.

1. **If you have multiple queries that need to be asked, please ask them in separate questions**.
2. **You must show *your* specific difficulty with the question is, and what you think the answer ought to be and why**. Do not just copy questions from your homework or a book verbatim.
3. I am not a lawyer, but you might want to be careful about copying large chunks of a book too. Asking a couple of questions you're having troubles with is fine, but copying large quantities of copyrighted material onto a StackExchange site is not a good idea.